# Tensowflow GraphDef weights loading differently on different platforms

Tags: tensorflow

I'm able to train a TensorFlow model and save to a frozen GraphDef in my Ubuntu development environment and then restore from that file.  The graph runs fine, producing reasonable predictions.

However, when I load the same graph on OSX (Sierra), many of the tensor weights are suspiciously close to zero.

Here's how I'm loading the GraphDef:

```
g = tf.GraphDef()
graph_filename = ".../frozen_inference_graph.pb"
f = tf.gfile.Open(graph_filename, "rb")
g.ParseFromString(f.read())
f.close()
```

I'm saving the GraphDef with this inference graph exporter: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py

I've confirmed that the graphs have the same number of nodes on both platforms once loaded, and I haven't found any nodes that are present in one graph but not the other.  Both graphs appear capable of running to completion (from input variables to output variables).  I've isolated the problem down to the weights for at least the first convolutional layer loading differently across different platforms (and I believe many others have the same problem).  This eventually results in nans showing up in a FusedBatchNorm layer, for which the epsilon weight is not being added to variance estimates on OSX (but, again, the different weights start with the first layer, which is convolutional).

Details of platforms / versions:

Works on: Tensorflow 1.3.0 running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-93-generic x86_64). This platform also has a GPU, though I've confirmed that the GPU is not being used to evaluate the graph.

Doesn't work on: Tensorflow 1.3.0 running on OSX Sierra, 10.12.5

Doesn't work on: Tensorflow Java implementation running on android (haven't confirmed the versions here, but I have confirmed that the output values are all zeros.  I'm fine focusing on the difference between OSX and Ubuntu for now).

Comment: It sounds like one of them is loading incorrect weights? If you can have a self-contained example that shows incorrect weights being loaded, that would be worth filing a bug